# Syntax error on hello="bonjour" python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, syntax-error

I try to launch a basic program in python which is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

hello = "world"
```

And I get this error :

```
File "toto.py", line 4
  hello = "world"
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But I'm sure it's the good syntax ! 
So where am I wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: is that the whole file?

Comment: If you remove the encoding, does it work?

Comment: Removed the python 2.7 (first line) and it worked for me (python 3.3). Try removing those first two lines and running it again, I see no reason why this won't work. Edit: Damn people, I know SO wants people to do research, but dude's having some weird problem with what is obviously his VERY FIRST program, show some restraint with the downvotes :( Also, op, try going through the lessons at Code Academy, just as a general tip.

Comment: Never ever will the shown code cause this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at your question title, you may notice something: the quotation marks are fancy.  And if I use the curly quotation marks `“bonjour”` instead of `"bonjour"`, that's the error message you'd see:

```
~/coding$ python2.7 hello.py 
  File "hello.py", line 4
    hello=“bonjour”
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Use `"` instead.

(I know your transcript makes it look like you *did* use `"`, but I'm pretty sure you didn't.  Whether that means you're running a different code than you think you are, or you pasted the wrong code, or your fancy quotation marks didn't survive being pasted into SO, I'm not sure.  But this is the underlying problem.)

Comment: Good catch, if that's the problem (can't tell from the post, but seems logical).

Comment: +1 Great, I was trying many things to reproduce the same error, but you nailed it. ;-)

Comment: Note that Python3 raises a slightly different error message here: `SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier`

Comment: @hcwhsa: that's a considerable improvement!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working ! 
I didn't have the good quotes in the code, I just correct it and it's ok !

Comment: @user2945293: No worries, we're glad we could help!